# asp.net (4) listview gives me troubles with generating id's

Tags: asp.net, listview, asp.net-4.0

i'm in a asp.net listview, in the itemtemplate.

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ClientIDMode="Predictable" ClientIDRowSuffix="Texttranslations_key"ID="lvwTextitems">
```

This is my code in the itemtemplate:

```
<span runat="server" onclick="openDiv('<%= EditItemDiv.ClientID%>')" style="width: 450px;"><%# Eval("Translation")%></span>
<asp:panel  runat="server" id="EditItemDiv" style="display:none">
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID = "EditItemArea" TextMode ="MultiLine" Rows="12" Columns="50" Text="<%# Eval("Translation")%>">
</asp:TextBox>
```

Now i have two problems.
First the span: i want the clientID of the asp:panel in the function openDiv(), so i can create some show hide functionality.
However, i get this as result:

```
<span onclick="openDiv(&#39;&lt;%= EditItemDiv.ClientID%>&#39;)" style="width: 450px;">
```

my code isn't seen as code, but as plain text, and i don't know why?

Second, this line gets me a runtime error (The server tag is not well formed):

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID = "EditItemArea" TextMode ="MultiLine" Rows="12" Columns="50" Text="<%# Eval("Translation")%>">
```

Can somebody help me out?

ps
at first i used this code for the generation of the id's: "myid<%# Eval("Id")%>" but that didn't workout either...

ps
i'm always getting in to trouble when using the Eval and the <%# %>, so it's probably some stupid thing (i hope)

Comment: The problem with your Eval not being well formatted is due to the double quotes that you use both to wrap the Eval in and the item name in the Eval. This would work: Text='<%# Eval("Translation")%>' notice I used single quotes to wrap the Eval while keeping the double quotes inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comment and by jamietre to fix the binding problem you need to change the code from:

```
Text="<%# Eval("Translation")%>"
```

to

```
Text='<%# Eval("Translation")%>'
```

As for the problem with the onclick of the span, it should work as you want if you just remove the `runat="server"` portion. I am not sure why, but it seems that adding this causes the controls to encode the onclick property.

If you need the runat="server" on the span then I will attempt to find another solution, but there are not guarantees.

Comment: "I am not sure why" but that's because that's the whole point to the ASP.NET .aspx model. If you want to use runat=server _and_ onclick then make the onclick an onclientclick ... asp.net server controls don't have a GUI element (unless you give them one) for the .aspx parser to use to bind an onclick to.

Comment: Your before & after are the same... just sayin'.

Comment: @jamietre fixed it. Thanks for bringing it to my attention

Comment: @drachenstern you aren't completely correct. First, adding an onclick to a server control will add that attribute to the final html that is sent back by the server and the javascript in it will work. Second, the problem is that ASP.Net server controls don't allow using the above expression syntax to set attribute values; even the OnClientClick doesn't accept the syntax, which only a few controls have anyway. What I didn't understand is why it doesn't evaluate the expression before setting the value of the attribute like is done with the data binding (#) and resource ($) expressions.

Comment: But that's not what you say in your actual answer. Your comment and answer say things that are about 150 degrees opposite, in my opinion.

Comment: @drachenstern I think that it is just a misunderstanding. The problem is that the javascript runs, but the ASP.Net control doesn't evaluate <%= EditItemDiv.ClientID %> and instead just encodes the <% %> part. Thus when you run it, it looks for an element with the id &#39;&lt;%= EditItemDiv.ClientID%>&#39; which doesn't exist on the page. When the runat="server" is removed the <%= EditItemDiv.ClientID %> is actually evaluated and not encoded. I didn't specify what I was confused about and I can see where misconceptions would arise. I do like the 150 degree rather 180 degree though :)

Answer (score 2):

For the first part, you definitely need to be using a binding expression:

```
<%# EditItemDiv.ClientID %>
```

The <%= %> scriptlet will have no context for each item. I assume you were "paraphrasing" the syntax you say you tried, so what didn't work before?

The "server tag is not well formed" is because you are trying to use double-quotes inside double-quotes. Change the outer to single-quotes:

```
Text='<%# Eval("Translation")%>'>
```

Basically, you can't nest similar quote types. Inline script will usually demand you use double-quotes, since single-quotes have a different meaning in c#, but you can use either double or single for markup parameter quoting. The upshot is that if you need to have inline script, use single quotes to wrap the markup parameter, which frees you to use double-quotes inside it.

If you need further single quotes in the output, e.g. to render a javascript parameter, just use `&#39;`. You could also use `&#34;` if you wanted to render double-quotes.

```
OnClientClick='openDiv(&#39;EditItem(<%# Eval("something") %>&#39;);'
```

Comment: <textarea cols="50" rows="12" id="EditItem<%# Eval("Texttranslations_key")%>"></textarea>, but i've got that fixed with the quote / double quote too, thanks! I think the problem is that in the onclick event i need 3 types of quotes: "onclick= openDiv('EditItem<%# Eval("Texttranslations_key")%>')" because i need quotes before the onclick, before the EditItem and in the eval statement

Comment: your code snippet isn't visible, put it in left-quotes to show in a comment.

Comment: Sounds like you got it... you can't use the same quote types as the wrapper inside it. So if you need to put quotes for a js function inside an eval parameter, use single quotes to wrap the event, then double quotes for the eval, then &#39; for further single quotes in the JS, e.g.  `onclick='openDiv(&#39;EditItem(<%# Eval("something") %>&#39;);'`